# Fitnesse: beginner error

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am starting with Fitnesse, and try to Test the following:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path C:\Users\binF\java

|import|
|org.magmax|

|multiplication|
|factor|factor|multiply?|
|4|2|8|
|44|12|8|
```

I have the file `multiplication.class` in the specified path, the code:

```
package org.magmax;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class multiplication {
    private ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void setFactor(int n) {
        factors.add(n);
    }

    public long multiply() {
        long result = 1;
        for (Integer i: factors) {
            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, I execute the Test and returns the error of the type:

**Multiplication
factor multiply?
4 The instance decisionTable_1.setFactor. does not exist**

Can you help me? I do not know to fix this error
Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: The standard convention for Java classes is to start their name with a capital. Does naming the class Multiplication make a difference?

Comment: As @Fried said, the standard naming convention says to start with cappital letter, but this is not the issue here. I think you must precede the class name, including package, with exclamation mark, like: !|org.magmax.multiplication| and remove the import section above it.

Comment: Thanks friends. I have generated the class "Multiplication.class", putting "public class Multiplication " and edit the Fitnesse page adding "!|org.magmax.Multiplication| " (after remove the import section above it), but returns the error "Could not invoke constructor for Multiplication[0]" and "The instance decisionTable_1.setFactor. does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Your test script and the class are correct. It is just a typo in your `!path C:\Users\binF\java`. The `!path` should point to the folder that contains the package.

I managed to reproduce the error by misspelling the path. Below are the screenshots

[image]

After correcting the path, below is the successful run of the test:

[image]